# iOS UICollectionview wrong render background color

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

[image]

As shown in image i have collection view i.e. the date one. The background color is 129BBF, it working fine in storyboard as matching with navigation bar color, but in runtime it shows lighter than actual color, I have cross checked all thing. Even checked opacity and alpha.
 What i'm missing here?

Comment: Check if you navigation bar is translucent.

Answer (score 1):

Check also the color space what you are using [image: Just an image. Don't look here :3]

I can't guarantee you that is is the problem, but it's worth checking